# Why SendToBack is not working with Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I'm using Delphi XE4 and trying to create 2nd form and set it as a background while the first form is transparent (AlphaBlend = true; AlphaBlendValue = 220)

```
    uses Unit2;

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Form2.Show;
      Form2.SendToBack;
    end;
```

The codes above are working with Delphi 7, but not with Delphi XE4 (Form2 still over on the Form1). Can anyone tell me why the codes are not working with XE4? And how to make it working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Check the setting of Form2's [`PopupMode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.PopupMode) property. It is likely set in a way that cause's Form1's window to become the parent of Form2's window, which would prevent Form2 from moving behind Form1.  The [`PopupMode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.PopupMode) (and [`PopupParent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.PopupParent)) property did not exist in D7, it was introduced in a later version to address z-order bugs that the VCL suffered from in earlier versions.

Read the following blob article for more details:

[PopupMode and PopupParent](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2004/02/10/295)

Comment: The Form2.PopoupParent property is nil (empty) by default and i have no changed it.

Comment: If i set the Form1.PopupParent to Form2, then SendToBack is working (Form2 send to back Form1) but when i close the application an error occur.

    uses Unit2;
    
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Form2.Show;
      PopupParent := Form2;
      Form2.SendToBack;
    end;

I have tried set PopupParent to NIL onClose event of Form1 but the error still occur.

    procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    begin
      PopupParent := nil;
    end;

Comment: Sorry, I meant PopupMode, not PopupParent (though they are related). Don't set Form2 as Form1's PopupParent. Try setting Form2's PopupMode to explicit and its PopupParent to nil. Leaving the defaults allows the VCL to decide which PopupParent to use when Form2 is shown, and that is usually the active Form (Form1 in this case).